# How to use a RequireJS module from a non-RequireJS site

Tags: requirejs, azure-storage

I've got a site that doesn't use RequireJS. I load all of my code in `<script>` nodes `index.html`.

I found a module on NPM, `azure-storage`, that I'd like to use. However the `js` files in the module contain code that assumes that I'm using RequireJS; The documentation says to use it via a `require()`, and the javascript files itself is littered with more `require()` calls.

I do not mind taking a dependency on RequireJS to consume this package. However all of the tutorials that I found gave me the impression that I need to restructure my entire application in a RequireJS style before I could `require()` the dependency that I found on npm.

Please tell me that I'm wrong. **Is there a simple way for a non-RequireJS site to consume a RequireJS module?**

In case it matters, my web app is built on AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is browsers don't support `require` or any notion of modularity, really.

Assuming you just want to assign whatever `azure-storage` exports to a name in the global namespace (which assumes `azure-storage` and its dependencies will only consume APIs available on the browser), there are tutorials for using [browserify](http://www.mattburkedev.com/export-a-global-to-the-window-object-with-browserify/) or [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html#examples) to that end.

Either of those will build the `azure-storage` package and its dependencies into a solid .js file you can use in a `<script>` node that will assign whatever the module exports to a global name of your choosing.